# Is there any Android TV that could act as a Bluetooth center?

Tags: bluetooth, android-tv, smart-tv, google-tv

I'd like to develop an app for Android TV that can control BLuetooth devices.

Is there any Android TV that could do that ?

Alternatively, could a TV box such as the Xiaomi Mi TV do that ?
http://www.mi.com/en/mibox/

Comment: It would be helpful to know if there are specific devices you are trying to connect/control or if you're wondering about the possibilities of connecting general Bluetooth devices.

Comment: I am wondering about the possibilities of connecting to general Bluetooth devices from the TV. For example, any Android TV app able to  play music on a Bluetooth speaker would prove it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Google Android TV [support page](https://support.google.com/androidtv/answer/6123183?hl=en) has instructions for connecting devices via Bluetooth. [This page](http://www.wirelesshack.org/how-to-connect-your-bluetooth-speakers-to-your-android-tv-box.html) (written in January 2018) specifies these steps for connecting Bluetooth speakers:

1. Find and select `Settings` from the app menu
2. Select 'Bluetooth' (may be under `Wireless and Networks` or `Remote & accessories`)
3. Use the `Pair` button on your speaker (or other device) to start the pairing process
4. Follow the dialog on the screen to complete pairing.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207033/connect-multiple-devices-to-one-device-via-bluetooth) on Stack Overflow, you should be able to connect up to 7 devices as long as they are above Bluetooth 4.0. The MiBox you linked to does have Bluetooth 4.0/3.0.

All this considered, **yes, controlling Bluetooth devices via an Android TV is possible.**

However, in relation *developing* an app to control Bluetooth devices, there are several in the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=bluetooth) now, but **development questions are best handled on [StackOvervlow](https://stackoverflow.com/).**

Comment: Thanks @jlehenbauer do you know any app for Android TV controlling a bluetooth peripheral ?

Comment: When you say control, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean connect to the peripheral in Bluetooth LE and send it command. The app on the Android TV would for instance connect to a Bluetooth speaker and play music on it

Comment: It sounds like this is possible using the steps above with a somewhat recent (less than 1 year-ish old) Android TV device.

Comment: Do you know if these steps can be done programmatically @jlehenbauer ?

Comment: No, but I'd imagine the much-referenced Tasker might be able to help.